# Magento Customer create and login not working in 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, ce-1.9.2.2

Already I have used bellow code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

In `app/design/frontend/my theme/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Same code used in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

But still not login or create user into chrome.

Any Solution for that??

here my code in register.phtml file.

```
<div class="account-create">
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
    <div class="fieldset">
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Personal Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address')) ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <li class="control">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
                </div>
                <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
            </li>
```

Same thing, login.phtml file

```
<div class="account-login">
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="white-bg">
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
<?php //echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <div class="grid_6 no-left-margin">
        <div class="registered-users">
            <div class="content">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Registered Customers') ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
                <ul class="form-list">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<? echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" name="form_key" />
                    <li>
                        <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="E-MAIL OR LOGIN" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Comment: `can you post how you add code of form key?

Comment: Did you try enabling template path hints and ensure your template is not getting overidden by a 3rd party module ?

Comment: Also try flushing your browser cookies and var/session

Comment: Hi @DigitalPianism, yes I have checked it, not override with 3rd party extension. And also, clear all cache and browser cookie, but still not work.

Comment: Does it happen on Firefox too ?

Comment: No, only in Chrome..

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment

```
<?php //echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

in login.phtml
 

In register.phtml 
Change from `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />` to `<?php echo echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Chrome specific issue, you'd try to check your `.htaccess` file, and disable any `mod_expires` directive for html files. I have experienced some issues with this in the past, as Chrome cache seems to work *more than desired*

Other problem could be cookies, I assume you have cookies enabled for Chrome. If that's the case be sure to clean all stored cookies (this can be a bit tricky with Chrome, the right way to do is: `Settings > History > Clear browsing data > select cookies`, discard doing it with any plugin or extension)